# Error registering Clang Checker: "out-of-line-definition of register"

Tags: c++, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to add my own checker to [clang's static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Following the [instructions for adding a checker to clang](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html), I have done the following:

Written a skeleton checker in `MyChecker.cpp`:

```
using namespace clang;
using namespace ento;

namespace {
    class MyChecker : public Checker<check::PreCall,
                                     check::PostCall,
                                     check::Location> {
    public:
      void checkPreCall(const CallEvent &Call, CheckerContext &C) const;
      void checkPostCall(const CallEvent &Call, CheckerContext &C) const;
    };

}

void MyChecker::checkPreCall(const CallEvent &Call, CheckerContext &C) const {}
void MyChecker::checkPostCall(const CallEvent &Call, CheckerContext &C) const {}

void ento::registerMyChecker(CheckerManager &mgr) {
  mgr.registerChecker<MyChecker>();
}
```

Added the source file to the Checkers `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
...
MPI-Checker/MPIFunctionClassifier.cpp
MyChecker.cpp
NSAutoreleasePoolChecker.cpp
...
```

And added an entry to `Checkers.td`:

```
def MyChecker : Checker<"MyChecker">,
  HelpText<"MyChecker">,
  DescFile<"MyChecker.cpp">;
```

When I try and compile clang I get the following error:

```
MyChecker.cpp:30:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'registerMyChecker' does not match any declaration in namespace 'clang::ento'
void ento::registerMyChecker(CheckerManager &mgr) {
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Why am I not able to register MyChecker?

Comment: So where is `registerMyChecker` declared?

Comment: (assuming that code part is from MyChecker.cpp) It is only mentioned on the line `void ento::registerMyChecker(CheckerManager &mgr)` - but that is definition, not declaration, and this is exact compiler complaint.

Comment: I am following the instructions for adding a checker [here](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html#registration). I don't know where the declaration is.

Comment: That tutorial looks like it is missing about 80% of instructions...

Comment: @VTT The other checkers have the same `ento::registerXXXChecker` declaration with no definition. You can see the other checkers [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers). I'm not sure how it works but I believe some macro magic is happening somewhere.

Comment: @VTT "*missing about 80% of instructions*". Welcome to clang documentation

Comment: All those declarations are generated [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/ClangSACheckers.h). But since there is no `Checkers.inc` in the repo I guess it is generated somehow as well...

Comment: @VTT A [`CheckerInfo`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CheckerRegistry_8h_source.html#l00090) struct gets created for each checker. The struct includes a function pointer to each checker's register function that gets called [here](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CheckerRegistry_8cpp_source.html#l00116)

Comment: I mean that `ento::registerXXXChecker` function declarations are generated from `#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.inc"` Which is probably generated from [this](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.td).

Comment: @VTT My build has a `Checkers.inc` file that has a line for each checker that looks like this: 
`CHECKER("security.insecureAPI.gets", gets, CheckSecuritySyntaxOnly.cpp, "Warn on uses of the 'gets' function", -1, false)`.

As far as I can tell, `MyChecker` was correctly added to `Checkers.inc`

Comment: Then you will need to include `ClangSACheckers.h` into your file so that declaration becomes visible.

Comment: @VTT That was it! If you want to post that as an answer with a short explanation I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So clang static checkers registration relies on file containing generated declarations for static checker registration functions - [`ClangSACheckers.h`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/ClangSACheckers.h). Static checker source file should include that header file and implement registration function `void ento::registerMyChecker(CheckerManager &mgr)`